# Infinite-scroll.js scroll threshold not triggered using fullPage.js

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, fullpage.js

I'm trying to combine infinite-scroll.js with fullPage.js in a wordpress theme.

fullPage is only initialized on larger screen sizes, and infinite scroll is working fine on smaller screen sizes.  After enabling debug in infinite scroll and running some tests it seems like the scroll threshold isn't ever triggered when full page is active (even if the scrollThreshold is set to 1).  Therefore the call to load more content is never made - again works fine on smaller screen sizes when fullPage has not been initialised.

What would be the correct way to combine these two plugins? - how can I load more posts when the last fullPage section is reached?

```
var container = $('#bl-full-page');
//fullPage JS only on larger screens
    if (windowWidth > 768) {
      if( container.length ) {
        container.fullpage({
          sectionSelector: '.portfolio',
          navigation: true
        });
      }
    }

    if($('.pagination .next').length > 0) {
      container.infiniteScroll({
        // options
        path: '.pagination .next',
        append: '.portfolio',
        hideNav: '.pagination',
        status: '.page-load-status',
        debug: true,
      });
    } else {
      $('.page-load-status').hide();
    }

    container.on('append.infiniteScroll', function(event, response, path, items){
        $('audio').mediaelementplayer();
        if ( $( 'html' ).hasClass( 'fp-enabled' )) {
          $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
          container.fullpage({
            sectionSelector: '.portfolio',
            navigation: true
          });
        }
    });
    container.on( 'last.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path ) {
      $('.post-end').show();
    });
```

I'm using the sage development theme and so fullPage and infinite scroll are being loaded using bower.
[Here is a live webpage which is exhibiting the problem.](https://blueleafrecordingstudio.co.uk/portfolio/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this.  I used the fullpage `afterLoad` option to detect if the user is on the last section and then called infinitescroll's `loadNextPage`.  I then made full page move to the last section when it's reinitialised.

```
var container = $('#bl-full-page');

    if($('.pagination .next').length > 0) {
      container.infiniteScroll({
        // options
        path: '.pagination .next',
        append: '.portfolio',
        hideNav: '.pagination',
        status: '.page-load-status',
      });
    } else {
      $('.page-load-status').hide();
    }

    //fullPage JS only on larger screens
    if (windowWidth > 768) {
      if( container.length ) {
        container.fullpage({
          sectionSelector: '.portfolio',
          navigation: true,
          keyboardScrolling: false,
          afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
          // Section indexes in fullpage start at 1
            if(index === $('#bl-full-page .portfolio').length){
              container.infiniteScroll('loadNextPage');
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }

    container.on('append.infiniteScroll', function(event, response, path, items){
        $('audio').mediaelementplayer();

        if ( $( 'html' ).hasClass( 'fp-enabled' )) {

          //remembering the active section / slide
          var activeSectionIndex = $('.fp-section.active').index();
          var activeSlideIndex = $('.fp-section.active').find('.slide.active').index();

          $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');

          //setting the active section as before
          $('.portfolio').eq(activeSectionIndex).addClass('active');
          container.fullpage({
            sectionSelector: '.portfolio',
            navigation: true,
            keyboardScrolling: false,
          });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Another option is using the option `scrollBar:true` in fullPage.js. Read the [FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions) to know more about it.